# GSA report with 'Searches that returned results' and 'Searches that did not return results'

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am using GSA 7.2, In GSA Search Report It have two Report types

- Searches that returned results
- Searches that did not return results

what is difference between this types?

I tried Last week Search Report with both types, I am getting few same Keywords and Queries in Both Report types with different Occurrences count. Here my question is if GSA is showing result for some Keywords and Queries then It should not show in without result type, May be my Understanding is wrong, Please correct me.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this issue is there for a long time.
Check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-search-appliance-help/ph2XgO7Gyd8) out. Not sure whether it is fixed or not, better check with google support.

BTW, Do you have user specific search (Role based search)? If so, just try to search using same term for all user/role and see any user/role gets zero results.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the reports, are you restricting the search to a specific collection and/or time range?

If you run a report for "All Collections" then you might see items show in both reports because users are searching against a collection that does not have the documents.

What you'd want to do is run a report for a single day.  If you see the same behavior for a single collection then download the search logs for that day and look for searches for that key term and see if the search query parameters are the same.  If they are different then there could be some malformed search queries being executed.  If not then it could be a transient issue with the GSA.